# Server's network capabilities are going into some sort of sleep mode?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, ping, windows

I'm having trouble with a server (Windows Server 2008 R2) on my network.

It is going down for short periods at a time, but not very often.

The interesting thing:

If I ping the server from my computer (we'll call this client-x) using the -t switch, I will continuously get no reply. However the second I ping client-x from the server, I can see the previous ping pick up a reply? It's almost as if pinging client-x from the server, wakes up the networking capabilities? Has anybody got any idea what is going on here?

Comment: I have also observed this on a few occasions.  What network card driver and version?

Comment: @GregAskew It is a virtual server (Hyper-V)

Comment: so.. what network card and driver is the host using? Is there a NIC Team involved?

Answer (score 0):

Is there a possibility that this server has been assigned the same IP as another machine on the network? This can create strange intermittent connectivity issues (e.g. periods of non-connectivity for 20 seconds at a time since it's a tossup which host responds to ARP queries first from a client on the network).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Nope there is definitely no other machine with the same IP. Also, the IP for the server in question has been reserved in the DHCP.